# How can I exclude comma from the matched string?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that matches strings between the commas and some more rules applied to it. When I use `,` to match, the comma is also included in the matched string.

I just wanted to tweak it a bit so it doesn't capture the commas and dots.

[image: Regex]

My Regex is - `(?i)(\bmarche\s(?:\d{5})?\-?(?:\d{3,5})|(?:\d{5})\-?(?:\d{4})?\smarche\b|[,]marche[\.,]|marche$)`

The strings which I'm using to match are -

```
Diabetologist,5,rue du marche,93160 Noisy le Grand,France.
Diabetologist,5,rue du lemarche,93160 Noisy le Grand,France.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of Marche,via Brecce Bianche,60100 Ancona,Italy.
ALL MATCH
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche,via Brecce Bianche,60100 Ancona,Italy.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345-1234,via Brecce Bianche,60100 
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,12345-1234 Marche.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,12345 Marche.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345,Italy
```

I have created the regex but that regex needs some tweaks so that it doesn't capture any commas.

Regex - https://regex101.com/r/0PhCK4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a match for either the start of the string or a comma, and then use a capture group:

```
(?:^|,)([M]arche(?: \d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?|(?:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)? [Mm]arche)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:^|,)` Either assert the start of the string or match a comma
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[M]arche`  Match `marche`  or `Marche`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
    - `(?:-\d{4})?` Optionally match `-` and 4 digits
  - `)?` Close te non capture group and make the whole group
    optional
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?` Optionally match 5 digits with an optional `-` and a 4 digits part
  - `[Mm]arche` Match  `marche` or  `Marche`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fiow8G/1)

Comment: litte imporve `(?:^|,|\s)([Mm]arche(?:\s\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?)`

Comment: @某某某 Thank you for your comment. If you add the `\s` then there will be matches that the OP wants to avoid. See https://regex101.com/r/kMlLn1/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird

Thanks for your comment. The above regex works excellently. But our previous regex was meant to capture a few more patterns which this current regex doesn't include. `Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,12345-1234 Marche.` Consider above string. which will be matched by our previous regex. I will also update the post for more clearance.

Comment: @SHIVAMSINGH Like this you mean `(?:(?:^|,)([M]arche(?: \d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?\b|\b(?:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)? [Mm]arche)\b)` https://regex101.com/r/HKYCLT/1

Comment: @SHIVAMSINGH I have updated the answer with the alternation for both variations.