# regex to match city and city + zip code but not the city name if its not either the city name or city +ip code by itself

Tags: regex, re2

I have the following regex in pcre2 to eventually be used in bigquery sql.
match either

```
a city name 
,.....,city_name,.....,
,.....,city_name
,.....,city_name.
for zip code 
5 digits or {5digits}[-|/s]{3-5digits} 
,.....,city_name zip_code,....., 
,.....,city_name zip_code
,.....,city_name zip_code.
```

```
(?i)(\bmarche\s(?:\d{5})?\-?(?:\d{3,5})|(?:\d{5})\-?(?:\d{4})?\smarche\b|marche.?)
```

It should not match when the city name is part of a sentence other then the city_name or city_name + zip_code.
Here is my attempt https://regex101.com/r/w4f9cb/1
I can't figure out the NOT MATCH part.

I can't figure out the NOT MATCH part. Its matching but I don't want it to MATCH I only want the MATCH to match.

```
And how can the comma be excluded from the matched result. 
ie match Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,**Marche 12345**
and not 
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of **,Marche 12345**
```

```
NOT MATCH
Diabetologist,5,rue du marche,93160 Noisy le Grand,France.
Diabetologist,5,rue du lemarche,93160 Noisy le Grand,France.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of Marche,via Brecce Bianche,60100 Ancona,Italy.
ALL MATCH
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche,via Brecce Bianche,60100 Ancona,Italy.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345-1234,via Brecce Bianche,60100 
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,12345 Marche
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345.
Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,Marche 12345,italy
```

Comment: can you show what is the original text and what do you expect as results for each value

Comment: also add more description as to what exactly is the logic

Comment: Try it like this with a capture group `(?:^|,)([M]arche(?: \d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?|\b\d{5} Marche)\b` https://regex101.com/r/0gd8vV/1

Comment: @The fourth bird
  
That looks great. 
How can the comma be excluded from the result. So that the comma before ,Marche is not included. ie the delimter is not part of the match. 


Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of ,**Marche**,via Brecce instead of
\n

Department of sea science,University Polytechnic of **,Marche**,via Brecce
\n

Comment: @dpl See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363578/how-can-i-exclude-comma-from-the-matched-string this seems to be the same question. The value is in capture group 1 which you can extract using code. What is the tool or language?

Comment: @dpl Like this? `\b[M]arche(?: \d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?` https://regex101.com/r/0XD5fx/1 As you have tagged `re2` you can not use lookarounds, so what you can do to not match the ones that you don't want is to match the leading `,` and capture what follows. Then extract the capture group 1 value.

Comment: The language is Bigquery SQL. I'll do some testing its mayeb what I want.

Comment: @dpl Then you can use https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract which will get the capture group 1 value.

Comment: Its not solved 
https://regex101.com/r/98EeC4/1

Comment: @The fourth bird

Can you put your solution in the main section so I can check the answered box.

Comment: @dpl Are you sure that this is not the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363578/how-can-i-exclude-comma-from-the-matched-string

Comment: @The fourth bird
I spoke to soon. 
still an issue https://regex101.com/r/BIusty/1 

SHOULD NOT MATCHED
Clinical Research Support Center,marche University Hospital.

Comment: @dpl I am not at my machine for the next 2 hours. I will take a look later on.

Comment: @dpl Like this? `(?i)(?:^|,)(marche(?: \d{5}(?:-\d{3,5})?)?|\b\d{5}((?:-\d{3,5})?) marche)(?:[.,]|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/7jNbVv/1

Comment: @ the fourth bird
I came up with a similar answer and increased the scope to accept a range of digits for the first set of digits

https://regex101.com/r/pHgXbW/1
 
`\b(?:$|[.,]) ` 
instead of 
`(?:[.,]|$)`  both work, Thanks.
`(?i)(?:^|,)(marche(?: \d{4,6}(?:-\d{3,5})?)?|\b\d{4,6}((?:-\d{3,5})?) marche)\b(?:$|[.,])`